# configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php5

I'm trying to install a program called phraseanet.  I ran the ./configure command and run into this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, Apache 2, PHP5 and Mysql 5

Does anyone know where I can find the php-config?  I can't find that file....

Comment: You can get the same error with php 8 as `php-config` was renamed to `php-config8`. I solved the issue creating a symbolic link `ln -s /usr/bin/php-config8 /usr/bin/php-config`

Answer (score 17):

To use php-config you will need to have the PHP development package installed, in Ubuntu you can install the PHP5 development package using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

After installing the php5-dev package, (on my Ubuntu installation) php-config can be found in:

```
/usr/bin/php-config
```

Comment: Note that the right php-config might be /usr/bin/php-config54 or /usr/bin/php-config55, etc. according to your PHP verison.

Answer (score 0):

that is a script that display the configuration from
the ink file - see http://linux.die.net/man/1/php-config
if you can not install it with apt try to download 
the source code from the php site.